# Google Analytics - measuring returning customers after abandonment

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I’m wondering if anyone can help me. I’m currently working on a project which involves trying to understand customers who have abandoned one of the stages within a checkout but then returned to the site at a later stage and converted. I would then break this down to the number of days before they returned. I’ve tried creating segments however the data doesn’t seem to be making sense. Has anyone any idea how I’d go about this? Is this even possible in GA or is this something I can only accomplish in BigQuery if at all?

Your help will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Google Analytics(GA hereafter) is counting a visitor as a new or returning user by persisting cookie values in client side(in the browser). So once a user is visited, It stores an id which is specific to that user (actually this user means the browser which had been used to visit the website). So when a user visits the site for the first time, GA will store a specific id in a GA related cookie in the client side. If the user visits the website again later in another session, then GA check if there is a client.id for that user stored in the client side. If it found then that user is count as a returning user or New user otherwise.

In Google Analytics, goto **Audience** -> **User Explorer**. In there you can see an aggregated view of each user(*client.id*) interacted with your website and clicking on one client.id will show each user's activities with the website(differentiated by sessions) and will show all the sessions related to that user with the information like time, URL and some other dimension values.
Also if you want to separate out New users or Returning users from each other, you can create a new segment with a condition checking for the **User Type** dimension against the values "**New Visitor**" or "**Returning Visitor**".

To measure returning customers after an abandonment and converted, you can create a segment as follows,

[image: segment to filter out Returning users with transactions]

Comment: Thanks for your responses but not sure this answers the question as the segment does not include the page with which they abandoned, but also how do we know how long it took the customer to return before purchasing i.e one session, two sessions, or days? etc

thanks again

Comment: you'll not able to filter based on the last page viewed on a session but instead what you can do is filter the sessions by checking whether it includes a particular page or not. rather it is questionable what you meant by "Later stage" in your question. and as @Ms.Easy described in her answer, there are no metrics like days between x and y. rather you should map what you need with the available metrics. FYI:  sessions and days are two different terms.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it's not possible in GA.
There are no metric like "Days between abandoned funnel and conversion" (only "Days before transaction" - between acquisition day and transaction day). So you need a date for abandoned funnel and a date for conversion separately: i.e. you need two reports.

I know solution, but Excel or smth like this is needed if you want to calculate days before conversion.

At first you need to have `Client ID` as a custom dimension.

Then create custom report contains dimensions `Client ID` and `Date` and metric `[Your Goal] Abandoned Funnel` (Goal with Funnel needs to be set).

And the second report - `Client ID`, `Date` and `[Your Goal] Complection`.

And to merge these tables using `Client ID` parameter.